# Using a custom vertex shader with THREE.Points

Tags: three.js

I see that Threejs has a Points Material to draw a geometry as points rather than as triangles. However, I want to manipulate the vertices using my own vertex shader, using a Shader Material. In WebGL, I think I could just call gl_drawArrays using gl.Points instead of gl.Triangles. How can I tell the renderer to draw the geometry as points? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found my solution right after asking the question. Just create a THREE.Points object instead of THREE.Mesh using whatever geometry and the Shader Material you want to use.

THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.ShaderMaterial(parameters));

Answer (score 8):

little addition, I had no joy until I added gl_PointSize to my vertex shader:

```
void main(){
    gl_PointSize = 100.;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.);
}
```

found the answer in the [GPU particle system example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/GPUParticleSystem.js).